# Fix some problems with a nice frame using tcolorbox

Tags: fonts, tcolorbox

For my book I'm using this code (I have 4 with similar aspect) to put the important definitions, notes, and other. Here there is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1]{colback=teal!10,coltitle=black,colframe=teal!30,fonttitle=\bfseries,title=#1, arc=0mm}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}{An example}
\lipsum[1]
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

and the output is:

[image]

I would like use the package `pifont` to put a general symbol as the picture below:

[image]

My problems are:

1. Why is there a rounded corner if I have writen `arc=0mm`? I would like to have an edge and not a rounded edge;
2. I would like the thickness not to be there at all or to be reduced to a very small line;
3. How to insert the desired symbol from `pifont` package in a lateral position as shown in the second figure, in a dynamic position, that is to say that you can move it either downwards or upwards.

Comment: @JouleV Thank you very much for edit my question. Have you fix also my English (I hope)? :-)

Comment: Hmm, I just edit the list formatting. I'm also not from an English-speaking country, so I would not do that ;-)

Comment: I think we have some questions about overlaying symbols on `tcolorbox` environments already. This **must** be a duplicate. There are also examples of such overlays etc, as well as there is a pretty explanation about the geometry options of `tcolorbox` in the manual. Reading the manual does not hurt!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer There is only an old question. You're right but my problem was adapted into my MWE my request. I have read, surely, the manual but I'm not very able to solve my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `arc=0pt`. This option fixes corner's inner radius while `outer arc` remains untouched. Use `sharp corners` option to get inner and outer sharp corners.
2. `rules`. Tcolorbox defines five rules around the box: toprule, bottomrule, leftrule, rightrule and titlerule (this one between title and upper part). You can fix each one with independence of others or all together with `boxrule`. To suppress of all them use `boxrule=0pt`
3. Overlay symbol. You can use `overlay` options to add any symbol or figure with `TikZ` commands. It's conveninent to declare the box as `enhanced` to allow `TikZ` commands.

All together:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{pifont}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1]{%
    colback=teal!10,
    coltitle=black,
    colframe=teal!30,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    title=#1, 
    sharp corners,
    boxrule=0pt,
    enhanced,
    overlay={\node[font=\Huge, text=cyan!70!black] at ([yshift=-4mm]interior.north west) {\ding{228}};}
    }

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}{An example}
\lipsum[1]
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much to all users. I like the simple question :-) Thank you again.

Answer (score 3):

Only answering the first question, because multiple questions in one post are not good:

The radius of the other corners is defined by `outer arc`, not `arc`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{mybox} [1]{
                colback=teal!10,
                coltitle=black,
                colframe=teal!30,
                fonttitle=\bfseries,
                title=#1, 
                arc=0mm, 
                outer arc=0mm
              }
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}{An example}
\lipsum[1]
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

[image]