# Frame created with tcolorbox adding the white holes

Tags: tcolorbox, overpic

Considering this question [Add a crease in the lower right corner with a shadow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/514195/add-a-crease-in-the-lower-right-corner-with-a-shadow) with the answer of the nice user @Ignasi, and the recent comments of @John Kormylo, @Cicada and @Ignasi on the use of `overpic`,

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{pifont}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{%
    colback=teal!10,
    coltitle=black,
    colframe=teal!30,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    title=#2, 
    sharp corners,
    rounded corners=southeast,
    arc is angular,
    arc=3mm,
    boxrule=0pt,
    enhanced,
    overlay={\node[font=\Huge, text=cyan!70!black] at ([yshift=-4mm]interior.north west) {\ding{228}};},
    underlay={
        \path[fill=tcbcolback!80!black] ([yshift=3mm]interior.south east)--++(-0.4,-0.1)--++(0.1,-0.2);
        \path[draw=tcbcolframe,shorten <=-0.05mm,shorten >=-0.05mm] ([yshift=3mm]interior.south east)--++(-0.4,-0.1)--++(0.1,-0.2);
    },
    drop fuzzy shadow,
    #1
    }

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}{An example}
\lipsum[1]
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

if it is possible, easily, to edit the MWE (with the same structure of the first image) adding an increase of the crease to the bottom with the white holes like in this image without to change the format and the `ding` symbol:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here `tcolorbox` option `interior titled code app={<tikz code>}` is used.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pifont}

\makeatletter
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{%
    colback=teal!10,
    coltitle=black,
    colframe=teal!30,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    title=#2, 
    sharp corners,
    rounded corners=southeast,
    arc is angular,
    arc=3mm,
    boxrule=0pt,
    enhanced,
    overlay={
        \node[font=\Huge, text=cyan!70!black] at ([yshift=-4mm]interior.north west) {\ding{228}};
    },
    underlay={
        \path[fill=tcbcolback!80!black] ([yshift=3mm]interior.south east) -- ++(-0.4,-0.1) -- ++(0.1,-0.2);
        \path[draw=tcbcolframe,shorten <=-0.05mm,shorten >=-0.05mm] ([yshift=3mm]interior.south east) -- ++(-0.4,-0.1) -- ++(0.1,-0.2);
    },
    interior titled code app={
        \path[save path=\mytcb@dots]
          let \p1=($(interior.north) - (interior.south)$),
              \n{r}={\kvtcb@leftupper+\kvtcb@boxsep},
              \n1={int(scalar((\y1)/5mm))},
          in
            ([xshift=.5*\n{r},yshift=-\n{r}+2.5mm]interior.south west)
            foreach \i in {1, 2, ..., \n1} {
              ++(0mm, +5mm) circle (.23*\n{r})
            };
         \begin{scope}
            \clip[use path=\mytcb@dots];
            \fill[black, opacity=0.25, use path=\mytcb@dots];
            \fill[white, transform canvas={xshift=.3mm,yshift=-.3mm}, use path=\mytcb@dots];
         \end{scope}
    },
    drop fuzzy shadow,
    #1
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}{An example}
\lipsum[1]
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your kindness. To increase the bend from the bottom right corner, is it possible to bend it a little more?

Comment: @Sebastiano You can adjust the numbers used in `underlay={...}`.

Comment: Ah, ok!!! Hence the bend is generated by `underlay`. Thankkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk youuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu.

Comment: Excuse me for my disturb. I'm trying several compilations variating the values of underlay but I am not able to increase the bene. Please, can you edit your answer? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Sebastiano I've added an answer to the original question, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/567255/79060.

Comment: Done! :-) +1 for the comment and the advice.